# Comma before ampersand in family-given order in German biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

In German biblatex-apa style I would like to have a comma before the ampersand in family-given order, just like in the American biblatex-apa style.

It's not there in the German style because the DPG doesn't have it in their manual. However, in my opinion, their variant of the APA style is missing this comma. In the original American APA style, initials following surname are an insertion that needs to be set off by bracketing comma (that is, before *and* after the initials). The same applies to German grammar.

I made a MWE but I am still looking for a fix for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[paper=A4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@UNPUBLISHED{7.09:58,
    AUTHOR         = {E. Blackwell and P. J. Conrod},
    TITLE          = {A Five-Dimensional Measure of Drinking Motives},
    HOWPUBLISHED   = {Unpublished manuscript},
    INSTITUTION    = {Department of Psychology, University of British Columbia},
    LOCATION       = {Vancouver, Canada},
    DATE           = {2003},
    langid         = {american},
}

@ARTICLE{7.01:12a,
    EDITOR         = {C. Haney and R. L. Wiener},
    TITLE          = {Capital Punishment in the United States},
    TITLEADDON     = {Special issue},
    JOURNALTITLE   = {Psychology, Public Policy and Law},
    VOLUME         = {10},
    NUMBER         = {4},
    DATE           = {2004},
    langid         = {american},
}

@INBOOK{7.02:25,
    AUTHOR         = {D. M. Haybron},
    EDITOR         = {M. Eid and R. J. Larsen},
    TITLE          = {Philosophy and the Science of Subjective Well-Being},
    BOOKTITLE      = {The Science of Subjective Well-Being},
    LOCATION       = {New York, NY},
    PUBLISHER      = {Guildford Press},
    PAGES          = {17-43},
    DATE           = {2008},
    langid         = {american},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{7.04:39,
    AUTHOR         = {I. Katz and K. Gabayan and H. Aghajan},
    TITLE          = {A Multi-touch Surface Using Multiple Cameras},
    EDITOR         = {J. Blanc-Talon and W. Philips and D. Popescu and P. Scheunders},
    MAINTITLE      = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
    VOLUME         = {4678},
    BOOKTITLE      = {Advanced Concepts for Intelligent Vision Systems},
    PAGES          = {97--108},
    LOCATION       = {Berlin, Germany},
    PUBLISHER      = {Springer-Verlag},
    DATE           = {2007},
    DOI            = {10.1007/978-3-540-74607-2_9},
    langid         = {american},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\textcite{7.09:58}

\textcite{7.01:12a}

\textcite{7.02:25}

\textcite{7.04:39}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

What it is supposed to look like:

Blackwell, E.**,** & Conrod, P. J. (2003). ...

Haney, C.**,** & Wiener, R. L. (Hrsg.). (2004). ...

But without adding a comma in cases of given-name order, which should remain like this:

... In M. Eid & R. J. Larsen (Hrsg.), ...

... In J. Blanc-Talon, W. Philips, D. Popescu & P. Scheunders (Hrsg.), ...

Comment: With a recent version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` lines are redundant.

Comment: Good catch. It's indeed a bracketing comma in German. Maybe pass this on to the package authors for correction, i. e. the APA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\addcomma\space\&\space}}
```

This only works with the most recent version of `biblatex-apa` (>=v7.6).

Normally, the comma in the author list in the bibliography is realised as an Oxford comma in `biblatex-apa` (even though that might not be the most appropriate way to deal with this if one takes your view on the interpretation of that comma). But the DPG and German in general do not use the Oxford comma, so we have to explicitly force a comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@UNPUBLISHED{7.09:58,
    AUTHOR         = {E. Blackwell and P. J. Conrod},
    TITLE          = {A Five-Dimensional Measure of Drinking Motives},
    HOWPUBLISHED   = {Unpublished manuscript},
    INSTITUTION    = {Department of Psychology, University of British Columbia},
    LOCATION       = {Vancouver, Canada},
    DATE           = {2003},
    langid         = {american},
}

@ARTICLE{7.01:12a,
    EDITOR         = {C. Haney and R. L. Wiener},
    TITLE          = {Capital Punishment in the United States},
    TITLEADDON     = {Special issue},
    JOURNALTITLE   = {Psychology, Public Policy and Law},
    VOLUME         = {10},
    NUMBER         = {4},
    DATE           = {2004},
    langid         = {american},
}

@INBOOK{7.02:25,
    AUTHOR         = {D. M. Haybron},
    EDITOR         = {M. Eid and R. J. Larsen},
    TITLE          = {Philosophy and the Science of Subjective Well-Being},
    BOOKTITLE      = {The Science of Subjective Well-Being},
    LOCATION       = {New York, NY},
    PUBLISHER      = {Guildford Press},
    PAGES          = {17-43},
    DATE           = {2008},
    langid         = {american},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{7.04:39,
    AUTHOR         = {I. Katz and K. Gabayan and H. Aghajan},
    TITLE          = {A Multi-touch Surface Using Multiple Cameras},
    EDITOR         = {J. Blanc-Talon and W. Philips and D. Popescu and P. Scheunders},
    MAINTITLE      = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
    VOLUME         = {4678},
    BOOKTITLE      = {Advanced Concepts for Intelligent Vision Systems},
    PAGES          = {97--108},
    LOCATION       = {Berlin, Germany},
    PUBLISHER      = {Springer-Verlag},
    DATE           = {2007},
    DOI            = {10.1007/978-3-540-74607-2_9},
    langid         = {american},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\addcomma\space\&\space}}

\begin{document}
\textcite{7.09:58}

\textcite{7.01:12a}

\textcite{7.02:25}

\textcite{7.04:39}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just wondering: If this is indeed a parenthetical/bracketing comma situation shouldn't there also be a comma in "Wiener, R. L., (Hrsg.)"? And maybe even in "Conrod, P. J., (2003)" though in that case one could argue that there is indeed a sentence-ending full stop there and double/triple punctuation is suppressed (i.e. *"Conrod, P. J.,. (2003)"->"Conrod, P. J. (2003)"). The full stop being the one at the end of "(Hrsg.).", but of course there is not always a "(Hrsg.)" so only the full stop survives ...

Comment: ... works like it is supposed to. You make a good point there. I agree, in the case of "Conrod, P. J. (2003)" there shouldn't be a comma because it is a sentence-ending full stop and multiple punctuation should be suppressed. The full stop appears also in the case of organizations: "American Psychological Association. (2003)." Though your first example got me thinking. I will do a bit of research on this and get back here.

Comment: It seems you are right. There is no comma before (Ed.)/(Eds.) and after initials and thus the comma after initials is an Oxford comma. Still I find it a little disturbing that family name and initials are treated equally by listing them in such a way, even though initials are clearly a subunit of the family name.

Comment: @PsychicBirdy I wouldn't lose sleep over it. It seems the entire thing is a bit inconsistent: Normally you don't have an Oxford comma in a list of two. I had never seen the initials as parenthetical insertion, but I can see where you are coming from ...